# Verify if a circle is completely inside a rectangle or not?

Tags: java, 2d, collision-detection, libgdx

I am a beginner in game development. I am using the libGDX library.

I'd like to know the best algorithm to verify if a circle is completely inside a rectangle. I tried using the the static method `overlaps()` of the `Intersector` class like this:

```
if(!Intersect.overlaps(ball.getBoundingCirle(), wall.getBoundingRectangle())) { // ball is a circle and wall is a rectangle
            ball.reset(midPointX, midPointY);
        }
```

but I won't be accurate. I have read a lot of algos for circle and rectangle collision what I want is to detect when the circle touches any of the side of the rectangle (while inside). I [read this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/84029/algorithm-to-verify-if-a-shape-is-inside-another) but it didn't help me.

Comment: You shouldn't ask two unrelates questions in the same post. Instead move the second question to its own post.

Answer (score 3):

Will the rectangle always be straight or can it sometimes be put at an angle?
If it is straight(not at an angle),
Then in the circle class you will have to define a radius and a center point and for the rectangle the top left and bottom right coordinates, then you could check if it goes outside as follows:

```
if(circle.getX()+radius>rectangle.getBottomRight().getX()){
    //it is outside of the rectangle on the right side
}
else if(circle.getX()-radius < rectangle.getTopLeft().getX()){
    //it is outside on the left side
}
if(circle.getY()+radius>rectangle.getBottomRight().getY()){
    //it is outside of the rectangle on the bottom side
}
else if(circle.getY()-radius < rectangle.getTopLeft().getY()){
    //it is outside on the top side
}
```

If it isn't straight then you should rotate it to align it with the axis and then also rotate the circle's center point. After that you can use the above calculations. (Thanks to Patrick Hughes for pointing that out)

Comment: Thanku I solved 1st part of my question with this answer, do you know anything about the second part?

Comment: If the rectangle is not axis aligned, simply rotate it to the axis and then go ahead and do the cheap calculations as shown above.  The circle center point will need to be rotated, too, but the radius will remain unchanged.

Comment: @PatrickHughes Thanks for pointing that out I've added it to the answer